# Call to undefined function apc_fetch()

Tags: php

Im using the below code to my project ,It is not working on locally
while running the code it was showing Call to undefined function apc_fetch() .

```
 $apc_key = "abc_list";
    $info = apc_fetch($apc_key);
```

I am using  xampp 3.2.1 ,php 5.4.20 , windows 7
In php.ini i used this line extension=php_apc.dll but still it is not working .

Can anybody please solve my Problem ,Thanks

Comment: I hope you saved and restarted your webserver after doing that.

Comment: yes shankar but still it is not working , any other option

Comment: php_apc-3.1.10-5.3-vc9-x86

Comment: What you downloaded is for PHP 5.3 version , but you are using PHP 5.4 right ? Here's the dll for 5.4. Try this. http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86.zip

Comment: You added it under `ext` folder right ?

Comment: yes shankar still is not working

Comment: In php.ini development file i added extension=php_apc.dll
apc.enabled=1
apc.stat=1

Answer (score 5):

you need APC extension to work with APC.

https://pecl.php.net/package/apc

download your APC extension which suites your PHPversion.  and install it on your  XAMPP, or WAMP

on your Apache server to work with APC(Alternative PHP Cache).

http://kvcodes.com/2014/06/solution-call-undefined-function-apc_fetch/

Comment: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ expired, it´s been a while also, do you happen to have any other resource to provide, thanx

Comment: for php7 you can use [APCu](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu) with an [APC polyfill](https://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc). Make sure to register the polyfill after registering APCu.