# php apc_store function cannot be recognize in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i simply call apc function like below

```
apc_store($data);
//or
\apc_store($data);
```

But both  of this cannot be called
Below is the error message from laravel
[image]

Can anyone help me solve this?
Here is the php documentation for [apc store](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114139/1227923

Comment: Are you running over cgi or fpm?

Comment: @btl i run over fpm

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i using ubuntu , can show me how to install that using apt-get ?

Comment: i already install but it's still same error , using command "sudo apt-get install php-apcu -y" btw , it don't have specifically php7 or etc , it just have php-apcu